# How to dynamically cast a list of based type to derived type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, polymorphism

I have a dll with the following hierarchy:

```
Interface ISchema {}

class Schema:ISchema{}

class TableSchema:Schema{}

class ViewSchema:Schema{}
```

I have another dll having the following hierarchy:

```
Interface ISearch {}

class Table:ISearch{}

class View:ISearch{}
```

The following code is triggering the search operation on Table or View according to user selection:

```
private void FindNowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // return Table or View according to user selection. (Property is an internal class helping to retrieve the selected type)
    var type = (ObjectsTypeComboBox.SelectedItem as Property).Type;

    // Create an instance of table or View as ISearch
    var instance = (ISearch)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Call to relevant Search (table.Search or View.Search)
    // _dataManager help to get the records from Schema hierarchy
    // text is the text to search
    var result = instance.Search(_dataManager, FindWhatTextBox.Text);

    // Show in DataGridView the result
    FindResultsDGV.DataSource = result;
}
```

Each search method returns a List. I need to display different columns on the grid. TableSchema and ViewSchema has different properties, casting as following is doing the job.

```
FindResultsDGV.DataSource = result.Cast<TableSchema> ; // or result.Cast<ViewSchema>
```

How can I dynamically get the correct type at this stage?

Any other solution is welcome

**UPDATE:**

According to @GiladGreen

```
public interface ISearchSchemaFactory
{
    ISearch<ISchema> GetSearch(Type schemaType);
}

public class Factory : ISearchSchemaFactory
{
    public ISearch<ISchema> GetSearch(Type schemaType)
    {
        if (schemaType.Equals(typeof(Table)))
        {
            return new BL.AdvancedSearch.Table(); // Getting an error here
           // Cannot implicitly convert type 'Table' to 'ISearch<ISchema>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
        }
        else if (schemaType.Equals(typeof(View)))
        {
            // TODO
        }

        return null; // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using Generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to change the ISearch as following:

```
Interface ISearch<out TSchema> where TSchema: ISchema
{
    TSchema Search(....);   
}

class Table : ISearch<TableSchema>
{
    public TableSchema Search(....)
    {
        //Some searching code
    }
}

class View:ISearch<ViewSchema>
{
    public ViewSchema Search(....)
    {
        //Some searching code
    }
}
```

Then what you can also do is have an `ISearchSchemaFactory` that will give you an instance of the correct `ISearch` that you need according to the `TSchema` you give it:

```
public interface ISearchSchemaFactory
{
    ISearch<ISchema> GetSearch(Type schemaType);
}
```

And the usage: `var search = factory.GetSearch(type);`

---

**Factoy Implementation Example**

```
public class MappingSearchSchemaFactory : ISearchSchemaFactory
{
    public MappingSearchSchemaFactory(Dictionary<Type, ISearch<ISchema>> mapping)
    {
        Mapping = mapping;
    }

    ISearch<ISchema> GetSearch(Type schemaType)
    {
        ISearch<ISchema> result;
        if(!Mapping.TryGetValue(schemaType, out result)
        {
            //Some logging or throwing exception behavior - depends what you want
        }
        return result;
    }
    public Dictionary<Type, ISearch<ISchema>> Mapping { get; set; }
}
```

This specific implementation gets for "someone" the mapping. A possible initialization code can be:

```
ISearchSchemaFactory factory = new MappingSearchSchemaFactory(
    new Dictionary<Type,ISearch<ISchema>>
    { new TableSchema(), new Table() },
    { new ViewSchema(), new view() }
);
```

But I'd less recommend this. I'd go look at `Dependency Injection` and `IoC Containers` to manage the initialization of my objects. I personally use `Castle Windsor`

Comment: you will have to call `GetSearch` method like this `GetSearch<ViewSchema>()` or `GetSearch<TableSchema>()`  so the problem still remains.

Comment: True. Edited the factory's method.

Comment: now your method is not generic so `ISearch<ISchema> GetSearch(Type schemaType);` will not compile.

Comment: It does compile. It uses the ISchema interface not a generic T

Comment: oh i see. yes it does.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary :)

Comment: @GiladGreen, first of all thanks, it looks great solution. I started to implement it but I am stuck. Please see my updated post

Comment: @ehh - Ok updating my answer now :)

Comment: @GiladGreen, this is not my issue how to wrote the factory. To simplify the issue, I'll just say that this line is not compiling: ISearch<ISchema> result = new Table();
Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Table' to 'ISearch<ISchema>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @ehh - Fixed it. Look at the line where I define the `ISearch` interface - I forgot to add the 'out`. See [Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @GiladGreen, sorry but this is not the problem. The problem is different. I cannot write: ISearch<ISchema> result = new Table();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116451/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-ehh).

Comment: @GiladGreen, your solution is working wonderful!. You were correct, I miss out in the interface ISearch<out TSchema>. Thank you a lot for your patience and cooperation. Chat with you was very helpful.